# Count the number of string occurrences within a .txt input file

Tags: java, input, count

Input file has data one line at a time in this manner: Line 1: string, Lines 2-4: ints, Line 5: string etc. I need to count the total number of strings and ignore the ints. How could I do this? Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Project5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
    String fileName = in.nextLine();
    int stringCounter = 0;
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        String SnumStudents = inputFile.nextLine();
        int numStudents = Integer.parseInt(SnumStudents);
        Student [] studentList = new Student[numStudents];
        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            String score1 = inputFile.nextLine();
            String score2 = inputFile.nextLine();
            String score3 = inputFile.nextLine();
            studentList [i] = new Student(line, Integer.parseInt(score1), Integer.parseInt(score2), Integer.parseInt(score3));
        }
        System.out.println("Name\t\tScore1\tScore2\tScore3\tTotal");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        for (int i=0; i< studentList.length;i++){
            System.out.println(studentList[i].getName() + "\t" + studentList[i].getScore1() + "\t" + studentList[i].getScore2() + "\t" + studentList[i].getScore3() + "\t" + studentList[i].getTotal());
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        Integer i = Integer.valueOf(SnumStudents);
        stringCounter++;
        System.out.println(stringCounter);
        inputFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem reading from " + fileName);
    }
    finally {
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

Input file:

```
9
Andy Borders
200
250
400
John Smith
120
220
330
Alvin Smith
225
300
278
```

Comment: See Regex (regular expressions)

Comment: We haven't been taught about using that. I need a method that is beginner java by nature.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get it to only add the strings and not the ints.

Comment: Please add linebreaks and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

A Possible way (Pseudo-code)

1. Initialize a counter (to keep track of the number of strings)

   ```
   int stringCounter = 0;
   ```
2. Use a [Reader or a Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

   ```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
   ```
3. Loop over each line and Determine if the line is a number by trying to parse the value

   ```
   while(scan.hasNext()) {
       String currentLine = scan.nextLine();   
       try {
           Integer i = Integer.valueOf(currentLine);
       } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
           stringCounter++;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Once you exit the loop your counter will have the answer

Comment: I updated it with my attempt. I can't get the two nameTotal variables linked though.

Comment: Please provide an example of the text file.... Are you reading actual numbers or the word "int"?

Comment: Added the input file.

Comment: currentLine would be whatever variable is holding the String reading your current line... and Read the Documentation on (Integer.valueOf)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Integer.valueOf(currentLine). What does that do? When I tried the code in Eclipse it just says currentLine can't be resolved to a variable. Does it need to be currentLine? Should it be the variable for the input file?

Comment: OK, I changed I changed currentLine and got it to work, however the counter is outputting a value of 0 which isn't correct.

Comment: Don't use Scanner.nextInt() you need.. Scanner.nextLine()

Comment: @SeumasFrew You are not correctly looping on your File... Updated my answer once more..